# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.9\www\Inventory\addclient.php on line 25

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP and get the message Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in .. on line 25. I would be ever so grateful if someone could help me with this error as it's really started to stress me out. Been on dreamweaver and it says error where it says $Username=... But I just can't seem to fix it

```
<?php
    $host="******"; // Host name 
    $username="******"; // Mysql username 
    $password="******"; // Mysql password 
    $db_name="******"; // Database name 
    $tbl_name="avaya"; // Table name

    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");


    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }
    mysql_select_db("inventory", $con);


    $addavaya="INSERT INTO avaya_pabx(critical_spare_id, serial_no, ,comcode, version, circuit_pack, classification, location, availability, date, client)
    VALUES ('". $_POST['critical_spare_id'] . "', '" . $_POST['serial_no']. "', '". $_POST['comcode'] . "','". $_POST['version'] . "','". $_POST['circuitp_pack'] . "','". $_POST['classification'] . "','". $_POST['location'] . "', '". $_POST['availability'] . "', '". $_POST['date'] . "', '". $_POST['client'] . "')";

    mysql_query($addavaya,$con)

    if (!mysql_query($addavaya,$con))
      {
      die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
      }
    echo "1 record added";

    mysql_close($con);

    ?>
```

Comment: FYI, you are **wide open** to SQL injection, and you **will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Learn to do prepared queries with PDO to avoid this problem entirely.

Comment: HAHAH! naks si rio nag sstack overflow. :))) -Seph :)

Comment: HAHAHA LOKO KA SEPH KELANGAN EE. :)) PATULONG NAMAN :))

Comment: tignan mo yung "critical spare id" mo kung tama yung spelling. cross check mo dun sa form kung saan galing yun and dito sa code na to. baka mali lang spelling or if hindi, it means na hindi niya talaga pinopost yung "critical spare id" :)

Comment: Okay na to SEPH :)) hahaha thanks padin :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a semicolon at the end of this line:

```
mysql_query($addavaya,$con)
```

Comment: thanks but is still encounter error in line 21 Notice: Undefined index: critical_spare_id in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.9\www\Inventory\addavaya.php on line 21

Comment: So you're probably not POSTing `critical_spare_id` (the error says it's not in `$_POST`).